# Procedure and multiple queries in MySql version 5.1.47

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i have a stored procedure that delete a rows from 3 tables.

```
 DROP procedure IF EXISTS `Epurer_Documents`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`dba_account`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Epurer_Documents`(IN start_E INTEGER,IN pas_E INTEGER )
BEGIN

DELETE gdan from ged_document_annotation_individual  as gdan
    INNER JOIN  ged_document_annotation as gda on gdan.id_ged_document_annotation=gda.id_ged_document_annotation
    INNER JOIN  ged_document as gd on gd.id_ged_document=gda.id_ged_document
    INNER JOIN  EpureridsgeFdolder as igf on gd.id_ged_folder = igf.id_ged_folderToEpurer
    WHERE igf.id_ged_folderToEpurer in 
    (select id_ged_folderToEpurer from 
        ( select id_ged_folderToEpurer from EpureridsgeFdolder limit start_E ,  pas_E) as x);

DELETE gdrs FROM ged_document_revision_seal  as gdrs
    INNER JOIN ged_document_revision as gdr on (gdrs.id_ged_document_revision_child=gdr.id_ged_document_revision 
    INNER JOIN  EpureridsgeFdolder as igf on gd.id_ged_folder = igf.id_ged_folderToEpurer
    WHERE igf.id_ged_folderToEpurer in 
    (select id_ged_folderToEpurer from 
        ( select id_ged_folderToEpurer from EpureridsgeFdolder limit start_E ,  pas_E) as x);

DELETE FROM ged_folder WHERE id_ged_folder in ( select id_ged_folderToEpurer from ( select id_ged_folderToEpurer from EpureridsgeFdolder limit start_E ,  pas_E) as x);   
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When i run it it show me a error :"" near ,  pas_E) as x); Delete gdrs From "",
but when i run it in a outher version of MySql it work juste fine.
so  i wonder if the oldes version of mySQL doesn't support multiple queries in a stored procedure.

Thansk

Answer (score 0):

Older MySQL version (<5.5.6) do not allow use of variables in LIMIT. Multiple queries in a stored procedure work just fine.